# Mysql на другом хостинге

Tags: mysql, база-данных, php, хостинг

Подключаюсь к Mysql базе с локалхоста, все отлично... А на сервере не работает... И нет ошибок, а скрипт(php) дальше не работает.
Хостинг базы от одного хостера, а хостинг сайта - совсем-совсем другой...

Вопрос: Это (разные хостинги) может стать причиной неработоспособности скрипта? Уже день убил...

Решил вопрос - на сервере как я понял не было драйвера mysqli, с PDO таких проблем не возникло!

Comment: Не работает, но ошибок нет? А скрипт почему-то дальше не работает. Во как! 
Впишите `error_reporting(E_ALL)` в самое начало скрипта и ошибки вылезут на свет. И уберите `@` перед переменными.
Чтобы подключиться к MySQL необходимо указывать именно те параметры, которые хостер и указывает для подключения. Я надеюсь, у вас в скрипте, который "на сервере", не вписан `localhost`, как хост для подключения (раз уж база лежит в другом месте)?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) - вписал...
@ - нету... без них пишу...
параметры для подключения от хостера... 
localhost не вписан, так как я сразу подключался к серверу, и с компа тоже...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вполне себе может не работать. Хостер базы как минимум можен НЕ принимать запросы снаружи, к примеру база настроена так, что слушает только localhost.
Может быть, что подключения по этому порту закрыты фаерволлом.